# Angular: How to close mat-menu if keyboard focus goes out of the menu items

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, accessibility, angular-material-7

I have a code as shown as below,

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-qhmxj1-restore-focus-manually-6nnoke?file=app%2Fmenu-icons-example.html)

I want to close the mat-menu when the focus goes out of the menu items.

When keyboard focus moves to the next element outside the menu, the menu should be closed.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: @alonso When the keyboard focus moves to the next element outside the menu, the menu should be closed.

Comment: check this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html